# Extjs 4 Live search combo How to reduce the 4 character limit

Tags: extjs4

I am using Live search Combo feature in my project.

Here is the URL.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/forum-search.html

for this component there is limit of 4 character

"Live search requires a minimum of 4 characters"

Can We modify this 4 character to 1 character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course we can

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    // Config options
    minChars: 1
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-minChars